# Is it overkill to wrap a collection in a simple class only for the sake of better readability?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented

I have the following map:

```
Map<Double, List<SoundEvent>> soundEventCells = new HashMap<Double, List<SoundEvent>>();
```

This `HashMap` maps `double` values (which are points in time) to the corresponding `SoundEvent` 'cell': each 'cell' can contain a number of `SoundEvent`s. That's why it's implemented as a `List<SoundEvent>`, because that's exactly what it is.

For the sake of better readability of the code, I thought about implementing a very simple static inner class like so:

```
private static class SoundEventCell {
    private List<SoundEvent> soundEvents = new ArrayList<SoundEvent>();
    public void addEvent(SoundEvent event){
        soundEvents.add(event);
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return soundEvents.size();
    }
    public SoundEvent getEvent(int index){
        return soundEvents.get(index);
    }
    // .. remove() method unneeded
}
```

And than the map declaration (and a lot of other code) would look better, for example:

```
Map<Double, SoundEventCell> soundEventCells = new HashMap<Double, SoundEventCell>();
```

Is this overkill? Would you do this in your projects?

Comment: one may argue that conceptually, this has been addressed in [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260) If your peers keep complaining about your way of doing things, be it one way or another, you better change to make them feel better

Comment: What is it that makes the list of sound events a "cell" rather than a list? Does this choice of words mean that a cell has or eventually will have different behavior than a list?

Comment: @DocBrown Why? The class is `private static` because it's only going to be used by the outer class, but it isn't related to any specific instance of the outer class. Isn't that exactly the proper usage of `private static`?

Comment: @Doc Brown, Aviv Cohn: There is no tag specifying any language, so anything can be right and wrong at the same time!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia : Java (I think it's pretty clear since judging by the syntax it could be either Java or C#, and the conventions used narrow it down to Java ;) ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not overkill at all.  Start with the operations you need, rather than starting with "I can use a HashMap".  Sometimes a HashMap is just what you need.
In your case I suspect it isn't.  What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
public class EventsByTime {
    public EventsByTime addEvent(double time, SoundEvent e);
    public List<SoundEvent> getEvents(double time);
    // ... more methods specific to your use ...
}
```

You definitely don't want to have a bunch of code saying this:

```
List<SoundEvent> events = eventMap.get(time);
if (events == null) {
   events = new ArrayList<SoundEvent>();
   eventMap.put(time, events);
}
```

Or maybe you could just use one of the [Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementations.

Comment: So you advocate using a class, which is essentially an information-hiding mechanism, as an... information hiding mechanism?  The horror.

Comment: Actually yeah, I do have a `TimeLine` class exactly for that kind of thing :) It's a thin wrapper around a `HashMap<Double, SoundEventCell>` (eventually I did go with the `SoundEventCell` instead of `List<SoundEvent>` idea). So I can just do `timeline.addEvent(4.5, new SoundEvent(..))` and have the lower-level stuff encapsulated :)

Answer (score 14):

While it may aid in readability in some areas, it also can complicates things. I personally lean away from wrapping or extending collections for the sake of fluency, as the new wrapper, on initial reading, implies to me that there may be behavior I need to be aware of. Consider it a shade of Principle of Least Surprise.

Sticking with the interface implementation means I only need to worry about the interface.  The concrete implementation may, of course, house additional behavior, but I shouldn't need to worry about it. So, when I'm trying to find my way through someone's code, I prefer the plain interfaces for readability.

If, on the other hand, you're finding a use case that *does* benefit from added behavior, then you have an argument for improving the code by creating a full fledged class.

Comment: A wrapper can also used to *remove* (or hide) unneeded behavior.

Comment: @RomanReiner - I'd caution against such things. Unneeded behavior today is often the programmer cursing your name tomorrow. Everyone knows what a `List` can do, and it does all of those things for a good reason.

Comment: I appreciate the desire to maintain functionality, though I think the solution is a careful balance between functionality and abstraction.  `SoundEventCell` could implement `Iterable` for `SoundEvent`s, which would offer the iterator of `soundEvents` member, so you would be able to read (but not write) as any list.  I hesitate to mask complexity almost as much as I hesitate to use a `List` when I may need something more dynamic in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping it limits your functionality to only those methods you decide to decide to write, basically increasing your code for no benefit.  At the very least, I would try the following:

```
private static class SoundEventCell : List<SoundEvent>
{
}
```

You can still write the code from your example.

```
Map<Double, SoundEventCell> soundEventCells = new HashMap<Double, SoundEventCell>();
```

That said, I've only ever done this when there is some functionality the list itself needs.  But I think your method would be overkill to this.  Unless you had a reason to want to limit access to most of List's methods.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution might be to define your wrapper class with a single method which exposes the list:

```
private static class SoundEventCell
{
    private List<SoundEvent> events;

    public SoundEventCell(List<SoundEvent> events)
    {
        this.events = events;
    }

    public List<SoundEvent> getEvents()
    {
        return events;
    }
}
```

This gives you your well-named class with minimal code, but still gives you encapsulation, allowing you to e.g. make the class immutable (by doing a defensive copy in the constructor and using `Collections.unmodifiableList` in the accessor).

(However, if these lists are indeed only being used in this class, I think you'd do better to replace your `Map<Double, List<SoundEvent>>` with a `Multimap<Double, SoundEvent>` ([docs](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap)), as that often saves a lot of null-checking logic and errors.)